# Environmental protection board game from 80's or 90's

Tags: identify-this-game

So I've been racking my brain and the internet to find this game I used to play as a kid. It was an environmental cleanup game where you have to clean up oil spills, pick up garbage, prevent air pollution etc. There were cards you pick up that have each of the problems and cards with positives like saving a species or something.

I don't think it was tv-based, and I don't believe it was cooperative. It was a square playing space and you would move your play piece around. When you landed on a space you might have to pick up a pollution card or nature card.

Comment: There are quite a few environmental cleanup themed games from the late 80s into the 90s, do you remember if it was a Co-op or TV show themed (e.g. Captain Planet)?

Comment: @KMR I don't think it was tv based and I don't believe it was cooperative. It was a square playing space and you would move your play piece around and when you landed on a space you might have to pick up a pollution card or nature card. Not much to go on but last time I played it I was probably 20 years ago.

Comment: I edited your question to include the information you provided in your comment. Please add any additional details you remember with another [edit].

Answer (score 3):

From what you are describing, it sounds like a 1989 game from Aristoplay called [**Pollution Solution**](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/14307/pollution-solution).  I have also played this game in the 1990's and I remember cleaning up various kinds of pollution by drawing cards throughout the game.

> Players are environmental managers in a township. A die roll determines which areas on the board get polluted, and players must make the right choice to clean up the polluted areas. Pollution can also spread to non-polluted areas. There are three levels of play.

[image: Boxed game Pollution Solution]